# Clarification regarding Homogenous systems in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, definition

So i have just started with Classical Thermodynamics..and i am reading Thermodynamics by **Bruno Linder**So I could not understand what he means in this portion-

> **If intensive properties are uniform throughout the system or they are continuous (as air in a gravitational field) then it is called a homogenous system..**

So i dont understand when he says **continuous**.

> ***What does it mean for an intensive variable to be continuous***?

If it means that it is a continuous function of something..in that case what is that something ?

Any sort of help will be great 
Thanks in advance

Comment: A continuous function of position within the system...

Comment: @lemon can you tell how can we define an intensive prop. Say pressure at a point (or a position) ...within the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine dividing your system into a grid of cells, each with a volume $\delta V$, and pick a single cell centred on $x$. Now multiply that cell an infinite number of times in all directions, like so:

[image]

The standard thermodynamic definition of whatever intensive variable you're interested in (e.g. pressure, temperature, density, concentration, etc) can be applied *approximately* to the cell centred on $x$ within the context of this infinite ensemble.

If the property varies smoothly (continuously) over space, then you can take the limit $\delta V\to 0$ and get a well-defined scalar field. Note that a continuous property is *locally* uniform and may therefore be treated as *homogeneous*.

Comment: So we do not need the concept of defining that variable at a particular point

Comment: @HiteshPathak Sort of. We *do* assign a variable to each individual point, but it's interpreted to mean its value within an infinitesimal volume $dV$ centred on that point. A bit like the wave function in quantum mechanics, say.